# Android : App Crash When scrolling List View with 2 Different Cells

Tags: android, listview

I want to implement the two cells type in my app Image and text so i'm just testing this, my app works fine and load perfectly but tis crashes when i start scrolling with the following error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2130968624
```

this is my adapter

```
  public class myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<myobject> {

    Context context;
    List<myobject> objectlist;


    public myadapter(Context context, int resource, List<myobject> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objectlist = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder2 tvholder;
        ViewHolder ivholder;

        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (getItemViewType(position) == R.layout.textcell){

            if(convertView==null){
                convertView= inflater.inflate(getItemViewType(position),parent,false);
                tvholder= new ViewHolder2(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(tvholder);
            }else{
                tvholder = (ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag();
            }
            tvholder.TV.setText(objectlist.get(position).getText());
        }else{
            if(convertView==null){
                convertView= inflater.inflate(getItemViewType(position),parent,false);
                ivholder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(ivholder);
            }else{
               ivholder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            ivholder.IV.setImageResource(objectlist.get(position).getImage());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(objectlist.get(position).getType()==1){
            return R.layout.textcell;

        }else{
            return R.layout.imagecell;
        }
    }

}
class ViewHolder{
    ImageView IV;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        IV = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.IV);


    }

}
class ViewHolder2{

    TextView TV;
    public ViewHolder2(View view){

        TV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TV);

    }

}
```

my object :

```
public class myobject {

    int type;
    String Text;
    int Image;
    public myobject(){
        this.type = 0;
        this.Text = null;
        this.Image = 0;
    }
    public myobject(int type,String Text,int Image){
        this.type=type;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Text = Text;
    }
    public int getType(){ return type;}
    public String getText (){return Text;}
    public int getImage (){return Image;}
}
```

Use in Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView LV;
List<myobject> myobjectList = new ArrayList<>();
myadapter myadapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV);
    myobject myobject1 = new myobject(1,"teeeeeexxxxt",0);
    myobject myobject2 = new myobject(2,null,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    myobject myobject3 = new myobject(1,"teeeeeexxxxt",0);
    myobject myobject4 = new myobject(1,"teeeeeexxxxt",0);
    myobject myobject5 = new myobject(2,null,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    myobject myobject6 = new myobject(2,null,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    myobject myobject7 = new myobject(2,null,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    myobject myobject8 = new myobject(1,"teeeeeexxxxt",0);
    myobject myobject9 = new myobject(1,"teeeeeexxxxt",0);
    myobjectList.add(myobject1);
    myobjectList.add(myobject2);
    myobjectList.add(myobject3);
    myobjectList.add(myobject4);
    myobjectList.add(myobject5);
    myobjectList.add(myobject6);
    myobjectList.add(myobject7);
    myobjectList.add(myobject8);
    myobjectList.add(myobject9);
    myadapter = new myadapter(this,0,myobjectList);
    LV.setAdapter(myadapter);
}
```

I really don't know what is causing this fatal error + is my implementation consider to be the most optimize approach for the 2 different cells type ?

any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: which line causes the error, you can post ur full error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before solving your issue I want to clarify something first. While using the `ArrayAdapter` you don't have to store yourself the list of objects or the context, since it is done for you when the adapter is created. that being said, every call like `objectlist.get(position)` would be something like this `getItem(position)`, and to obtain the context you simply call `getContext`.

Now let's explore the issue. According to `Adapter` class [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)), the `getItemViewType(int position)` method has to return a value between `0` and `getViewTypeCount() - 1`.

> An integer representing the type of View. Two views should share the same type if one can be converted to the other in getView(int, View, ViewGroup). Note: Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1. IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE can also be returned.

The problem in you code is that you are returning the `id` of a layout file, which usually is a very big number, and thus `IndexOutOfBounds` is thrown. 
A possible solution for this would be to return the `getItem(position).getType() - 1` instead of what you are currently returning. After this, the `getView` method can be changed to match the different layouts and view holders.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder2 tvholder;
    ViewHolder ivholder;

    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textcell, null);
                tvholder  = new ViewHolder2(convertView);
                tvholder.TV.setText(getItem(position).getText());
                convertView.setTag(tvholder);
                break;
            case 1:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagecell, null);
                ivholder  = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                ivholder.IV.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImage());
                convertView.setTag(ivholder);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                tvholder = (ViewHolder2) convertView.getTag();
                tvholder.TV.setText(getItem(position).getText());
                break;
            case 1:
                ivholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                ivholder.IV.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImage());
                break;
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: many thanx man, just 1 more thing do u consider this code as the most optimized even for remote data ?

Comment: By remote data you are referring to data from a web service or something like this?